# Expressing Flux of irrotational vector field crossed with gradient of scalar field

Tags: vector-analysis, stokes-theorem, greens-theorem

For my homework, I'm given a question that wants me to find the flux of **F** × ∇φ through a surface S enclosed by a curve C, where **F** is irrotaional and φ is a scalar function.

Flux is $\iint_S u \cdot n dS$, which in this case, ***u*** = F × ∇φ so the flux is$\iint_S F × ∇φ \cdot n dS$. This looks very similar to Stoke's thm,

$\iint_S ∇ ×  u \cdot n dS = \int_C F \cdot dr$

but is missing ∇ × in front of ***u***, so I was wondering if there is some property or theorem of line integrals that I'm missing to move ∇ × inside the integral. I also know that since **F** is conservative, **F** = ∇f for a scalar function f, and that ∇f × ∇φ = 0, which would make the integral zero, but I feel like I'm not supposed to do that since the question wants us to express the flux as a line integral. Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: F is irrotational so F can be written as gradient of some scalar field f. What is the cross product of the gradient of two scalar fields?